# Excel formula does not work: too many arguments

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to run this formula:

```
=IF(AND(D4="Dr",D5="Dr",D10="Cr"),C4-C8-C9-C10-C5+C11,
IF(AND(D4="Cr",D5="Cr",D10="Dr"),C4+C8+C9-C10-C5-C11),
IF(AND(D4="Cr",D5="Dr",D10="Dr"),C4+C8+C9-C10+C5-C11),
IF(AND(D4="Dr",D5="Cr",D10="Cr"),C4-C8-C9-C10+C5-C11),
C4+C8+C9+C10+C5+C11))
```

But it is showing `you have entered too many arguments` error... can anybody help me with this formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF(AND(D4="Dr",D5="Dr",D10="Cr"),C4-C8-C9-C10-C5+C11,
IF(AND(D4="Cr",D5="Cr",D10="Dr"),C4+C8+C9-C10-C5-C11,
IF(AND(D4="Cr",D5="Dr",D10="Dr"),C4+C8+C9-C10+C5-C11,
IF(AND(D4="Dr",D5="Cr",D10="Cr"),C4-C8-C9-C10+C5-C11,
C4+C8+C9+C10+C5+C11)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift rply I think thi is working. I have tested this with an additional condition. It is working .  will update..thank you very much

Comment: Hi @SreenathPk please make sure to accept Sebastian's answer if you're happy with the solution. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info.